How do I make my vinyl folder bend like a realistic vinyl folder (two-folded)
I am making a vinyl folder and aim to animate it. The model is done now I have to attach armature to it. Completely new to the armature feature and I learn as I go. I have put two "bones", one for each side and done weight painting where each bone is only supposed to control its own side.
The problems I run into is that it still distorts the opposite side when I rotate the armature for one side. The closest I got was that the spine bended into itself as well, so when you rotate both sides 90 degrees towards each other, they just intertwine, where as I want to have the spine of just a few millimeters to be rigid and untouched by the armature so that it separates the two sides.


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Oh, I thought it's easy to answer but oww, you have several problems here. Let's have a look...
1. Mesh Geometry

the cover is very thin but it has extra edge loops in depth. I would remove them. Less geometry -> better performance & less problems
your mesh has serveal overlapping faces. There are several undivided large faces, stacked up to 3x on each other + 2 long, small faces at the top and bottom.
You can see them when the deformation of the Armature is active in Edit mode
Remove the overlapping faces. You can select one and then use menu Select > Select Similar > Area to get the large ones, the other one you need to select manually (only 2) because they have the same area as the square ones.

2. Modifier Stack

make sure you have only one Armature modifier on the stack. It should be the first modifier on top so it can use the base mesh with the weights you defined
add more modifiers of your choice, e.g. Bevel, Subdivision Surface etc. They create additional geometry, but the Armature modifier comes first and doesn't care (less work for it, original weights -> better performance and better deformation).

3. Apply Scale, Rotation and Location


it's a good idea to move the armature and the mesh to the world origin (0,0,0) so it sits in the XY plane. This way you can easily pose it on the ground or on a shelf.
the center of the mesh and the armature should be in the center (X=0) and face you (front view) so mirroring works properly. (just saying, it's already the case with your model)
now you can apply the transformations. Your armature has not apply them. In consequence, the X-mirroring is messed up. Apply them before you start with rigging (Ctrl+A in Object mode).
note that for Blender, -0 is not the same as 0 (see Y-Rotation of the mesh)
when you have applied the Location the origin (little orange dot) will be at (0,0,0). Applied scale is (1,1,1) and rotation is (0°,0°,0°). For the mesh you can reset the origin back to geometry if you like

3. The Rig / Armature


to have the back of the vinyl cover stay undeformed, add a center deform bone. This bone also acts as the root of your rig so you can easily move and rotate it
give the bones proper names, e.g. Center, Cover.L and Cover.R. The suffix (.L) in their names makes sure the X-mirror works. Blender is very tolerant when it comes to suffixes, you can also use .l or .left or _left or _L ...
make the Center bone the parent of the Cover.* bones with the Keep Offset option (Ctrl+P)
enable the bone axes in the Viewport Display option and adjust the Bone Roll so that the bone's Z-axis points up/down. This way you can rotate it around the global Z-axis and it will rotate as you expect and X-symmetry/mirroring works properly.

Weight Painting, finally

Last the but least, you need to fix the weights for the bones. They are stored in vertex groups that have the same names as the bones.
You can do it in Weight Paint mode -or- in Edit mode with the [X] Vertex Group Weights overlay enabled. (Blender 4.x has a new extra overlay dropdown menu, the right one. In older versions the option is in the left dropdown menu)
Ideally, the sum of the weights should be normalized (sum=1.0).

Thank you very much for your thorough answer. I got stuck at the third part: "to have the back of the vinyl cover stay undeformed, add a center deform bone. This bone also acts as the root of your rig so you can easily move and rotate it"
How do I add a center deform bone that has the left and right bone grouped beneath it? Thank you

Hi. Simply select the armature and switch to Edit mode, add a new bone with Shift+A. It's the center bone, press F2 to rename it. Then select the left and right bones (=highlighted in orange) and finally the new center bone (=highlighted in yellow=will be the parent). Then press Ctrl+P and select Keep Offset. This will make the left+right bones children of the center bone. That's it. The bone hierarchy in the outliner should now look as shown in the screenshot (3.).
